# NW.js Windows 10 Taskbar icon shows always default

Tags: windows, icons, node-webkit, taskbar

In Windows 10 the taskbar is not showing my custom-made icon. I am using the latest (at the moment of writing) 0.51.1 version of nw.js and the taskbar icon always defaults doesn't matter what I am doing. Even though the .exe icon is changing on the build and behaves as expected.
Have anyone managed to solve this issue? I read almost all issues log on this topic on the official nw.js Github page but it doesn't help and seems like the issue still happens for some users.

[image]

here is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "com.domain.product",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "build": {
    "nwVersion": "0.51.1",
    "nwFlavor": "normal",
    "strippedProperties": [ "scripts", "devDependencies", "build", "chromium-args"],
    "mac": {
      "name": "Product Name",
      "icon": "ProductName.icns"
    },
    "win": {
      "name": "ProductName",
      "icon": "icon/ProductName.ico"
    },
    "output": "../build"
  },
  "window": {
    "width": 314,
    "height": 660,
    "frame": false,
    "transparent": true,
    "toolbar": false,
    "resizable": false
  },
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-remote": [ "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more complex example, but look for how icons are handled in the the window setting and in the build settings:

- https://github.com/nwutils/nw-vue-cli-example/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Finally, I got this working! Thank you for your help. I'm not sure but maybe the problem was in the size of my png icon. When I put my png it won't pick it up but when I put your icon it became work. I increased the size of my png icon and it also started to work correctly. Is the png used only for the taskbar icon?

Comment: Yes each OS has it's own requirements, but 256x256 is pretty safe anywhere

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the 'window.icon' property to your package.json. Something similar to:

```
"window": {
  "icon": "./build/my-icon.png"
},
```

See the Manifest format documentation for more details: https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#icon

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added this but unfortunately, that doesn't work for me. I even tried to reset the Windows icons cache but to no avail.

Comment: Thank you for your help your answer also was correct!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in v0.74-0.75 that makes this happen. The last version to work well with the taskbar icon in Windows 10/11 is 0.72. See: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/8039

As of today, this has not been fixed yet.

If you are not using any of the new added features in 0.74-0.75, you may have to downgrade NWjs to 0.72 for now.